# Newly transferred Drupal site - Clean URL broken

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, wamp, clean-urls

I had a drupal site on my local wamp server but after having to reformat my computer and reinstalling wamp and all that, Clean URLS is messing up. I made sure my apache had mod_rewrite enabled and after that i just get a 404 error for everything. When i try to login i also get a 404 error. What can i do? I've looked for a while and cant find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's mod_rewrite that needs to be enabled.

Comment: Yeah i accidentally wrote mod_overwrite

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Had to navigate to the login page directly (/?q=user) rather then just using the login block. Then navigated directly to the clean url page (www.mydomain.com/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls) and disabled them.